# How does TimeUnit.class enum operation work?

Tags: java, enums

How exactly does the enum in the TimeUnit API work? Particularly what does the below syntax mean?

```
public enum Name {
    CONSTANT { }
}
```

I have been following the enum tutorial [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html), but it doesn't really go into the details of the above syntax. What is the thing inside the constant? Is it an anonymous class with their own methods? Then what are all those methods outside of the constants? I'm so confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `{}` the "abstract" methods are implemented.
See it as the body of a class that extends - to follow your example - "Name".
So if you have a method in `Name` - let's say

```
public String someMethod(){ throw new AbstractMethodError(); /*Or default implementation.*/ }
```

then you'd have to implement that in

```
CONSTANT{
    public String someMethod() {  return "green eggs and ham"; }
}
```

And that's what is done in `TimeUnit` - it defines abstract methods for converting different units and the elements implement the conversion methods for their magnitude.

Comment: So let me get this straight. Within the {} is an extension of the enum, therefore any method of the enum that is defined as abstract must also be implemented. In TimeUnit's case, it is the "excessNano(long,long)" method - which is the only method defined as abstract. All the other methods within the {} are basically just overriding existing enum methods... So essentially enum constants can be anonymous class within an enum. Can they have their own methods? If so, why even declare the method within the enum, why not just declare them within the Constants?

Comment: The enum class is the "interface". You usually wouldn't want different methods for each Constant. But as in TimeUnit you might want different implementations of the same method. That is converting seconds to millis, minutes to millis and so on. And yes, it is overriding. Just that in TimeUnit (at least in the OpenJDK implementation) some of the methods are made abstract by throwing the AbstractMethodError. That's why I put abstract in " ...

Comment: If it is the "interface" why are some methods being left out of the implementation? eg timedWait(), timedJoin(), and sleep(). Just to clarify... if I remove toNano, toMicros etc inside the CONSTANTS, this is still legal right?

Comment: timedWait() is one example of a default-implementation. All of the "Constants" share that implementation. If you removed one of the overrides - for example toNano - it would throw the "AbstractMethodError" from the default implementation. But if you removed that throw and replaced it with some legal code, then it would most probably not do what it is supposed to do any more, but it would compile and execute.

Answer (score 0):

Enums are classes too, their constants can be viewed as instances of the class. If you look at a normal class, if you do something like:

```
Clz obj = new Clz() {}
```

you are creating an anonymous subclass. This is true for enum values too. The methods outside of the enum values are the methods available for all the enum values(think like the public interface with default implementations, if any). If you want to override a method for a particular enum value, that's the way to do it.